# interactive facebook application Open Graph Object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I saw at facebook the app from nike run

It appears at my wall with an interactive graph

how can I made one like this?

I'm torn between Graph Api and Open Graph, some suggest??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these Posts that are coming up now seems to use Flash and just embed them in the Post. The interaction can be made by the use of custom Open Graph objects, by adding following meta tags on the URL representing the Open Graph Object

```
 <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb">
    <meta property="fb:app_id"       content="APP_ID" />
    <meta property="og:type"         content="game" />
    <meta property="og:url"          content="http://example.com/embed/" />
    <meta property="og:title"        content="Beat Gareth's high score" />
    <meta property="og:description"  content="Gareth scored 2800, can you beat it?" />
    <meta property="og:image"        content="http://example.com/game.png" />
    <meta property="og:video"        content="http://example.com/game.swf" />
    <meta property="og:video:width"  content="398" />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="299" />
    <meta property="og:video:type"   content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

And publishing on the User's feed endpoint as

```
POST /USER_ID/feed?
  link=http://example.com/embed/
  access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

For more detailed on How to do this check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-gaming/).